# java program that make hard for os to format the removable disk

Tags: java, linux, windows, operating-system

Is there any way to create a java program that can executes itself while in a removable disk and cannot let any windows utilities or some third party software format that drive.

Comment: So you are running Linux and want to protect yourself from windows tools? Why should a windows tool trying to format your drive?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: the idea doesn't make sense in the first place. You see, any Java program would sit **atop** of any operating system. So, if your **operating system** decides to do something; how could something that runs **atop** of your OS (and that doesn't control your OS) prevent your OS from doing that?

If somebody has physical control over that drive; then there is **nothing** that you can do to prevent that person from erasing, formatting, ... that drive.

There might certain "workarounds"; such as hiding partitions; but the bitter truth is: unless you are able to some "hardware-based" write protection (that can't be disabled without destroying the drive), there is nothing you can do (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/25463/prevent-a-hard-drive-from-being-formatted) for a similar question .. receiving similar answers).

Comment: To extend on this answer you should also note that Java programs aren't made for jobs like these anyway. The only way to protect a drive from being manipulated is by either doing it on some sort of a hardware level (write protection) or using some sort of software like GParted to hide the drive. See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/25463/prevent-a-hard-drive-from-being-formatted) for more information.

Comment: @px06 Thanks for your input; updated my answer!